# Append string data to std::vector<std::byte>>

Tags: c++, byte, std, c++17

I'm implementing a HTTP server and the API I follow define the raw response data as a `std::vector<std::byte>>`.

I store http responses headers as `std::string` in my code and at some point I have to write them to to raw response data before sending it back.

The thing is, I cannot find a clean way to write/append data from a `std::string` to my `std::vector<std::byte>>` (by clean way I mean not looping on the string and appending each char).

What is the best way to do that ?

Side question: What is the best way to read a string from a `std::vector<std::byte>>` ?

Comment: [Insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) at the end using iterators?

Comment: And to create a string, use iterators as well ([`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) have a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) taking an iterator pair)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Not sure I understand what you mean. Something like this ? `    std::string rr = "http/1.1";
    std::vector<std::byte>> raw;
    raw.insert(raw.begin(), rr.begin(), rr.end());`

Comment: Does not work with C++17 :) `char` do not fit in `std::byte` `std::transform(headers.begin(), headers.end(), std::back_inserter(response), [](char c) { return std::byte(c); } );` where lambda is `encode()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `char` do cannot be converted to [`std::byte`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). Its defined as scoped enum:

```
enum class byte : unsigned char {} ;
```

> #### [cppreference.com std::byte](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte)
>
> A numeric value `n` can be converted to a byte value using `std::byte{n}`, due to C++17 relaxed enum class initialization rules.

What you can do is use a helper function or lambda:

```
std::string headers;
std::vector<std::byte> response;

response.reserve(response.size() + headers.size());  // Optional
std::transform(headers.begin(), headers.end(), std::back_inserter(response),
    [](unsigned char c) { return std::byte{c}; }              // or `encode(c)`
);
```

You can also resize the `response` and skip the `back_inserter`:

```
const auto response_size = response.size();
response.resize(response_size + headers.size());
std::transform(headers.begin(), headers.end(), std::next(response.begin(), response_size),
    [](unsigned char c) { return std::byte{c}; }
);
```

Actually the whole will be optimized by the compiler to something similar to `std::copy`.

Or just replace `std::byte` with a `char` and use `std::vector::insert()` or `std::copy()`.

Answer (score 5):

Just use the ranged-`insert` overload ([#4](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)):

```
void extend(std::vector<std::byte>& v, std::string const& s) {
    auto bytes = reinterpret_cast<std::byte const*>(s.data());
    v.insert(v.end(), bytes, bytes + s.size());
}
```

You can read `char` as `byte`, it's a permitted alias.

Answer (score 1):

First start with a `gsl::span` or similar.

```
template<class T>
struct span {
  T* b =0, *e = 0;
  T* begin() const { return b; }
  T* end() const { return e; }
  std::size_t size() const { return end()-begin(); }
  bool empty() const { return end()==begin(); }
  span( T* s, T* f ):b(s),e(f) {}
  span( T* s, std::size_t len ):span(s, s+len) {}

  template<class Uptr>
  using is_compatible = std::is_convertible< Uptr*, T* >;

  template<class R,
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<std::decay_t<R>, span>{}, bool> = true,
    std::enable_if_t<is_compatible<decltype(std::declval<R&>().data())>{}, bool> = true
  >
  span( R&& r ):
    span(r.data(), r.size())
  {}
  template<class U, std::size_t N,
    std::enable_if_t<is_compatible<U*>{}, bool> = true
  >
  span( U(&arr)[N] ):span(arr, N) {}
};
```

now we have an abstraction for "possibly mutable view into contiguous `T`s".

```
std::vector<std::byte> concat_string( std::vector<std::byte> lhs, span<char const> rhs ) {
  lhs.reserve(lhs.size()+rhs.size());
  lhs.insert( lhs.end(), (std::byte const*)rhs.begin(), (std::byte const*)rhs.end() );
  return rhs;
}
```

this assumes you don't want to embed the `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

you'll want something like the following. I realize this still uses copy but there is only the one memory allocation which is the expensive part.

```
std::vector<std::byte> data;
std::string input;
...
data.reserve(data.size() + input.size());
std::copy(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(data));
```

Comment: This does not compile  :/   `error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<std::byte> >’ and ‘const char’)`